# LaTeX tableofcontents not rendering a new page?

Tags: latex, beamer

So im making a presentation and for some reason, i can't create a new page for my tableofcontents.

The list of the tableofcontents is longer and i need to split it up to two pages to be able to display all informations, but it doesn't work (i tried \clearpage and \newpage without success)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

%%%% graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%START THEME SETTINGS
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\title{stuff}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents

\end{frame}


\section{x}
\subsection{Introduction}
\subsection{Use Cases}

%------------------------------------------------
\section{xyz}
\subsection{Introduction}
\subsection{Use cases}
\subsection{Hyypervisors}
\subsection{Hypervisors Types}
\subsection{Memory Management}
\subsection{Memory Overcommitment}
\subsection{Memory Compression}
\subsection{Memory Transparent Page Sharing}
\newpage %<- this doesn't work!


%--------------------------------------------
\section{xy}
\subsection{Motivation}
\subsection{Virtualization}
\subsection{Emulation}

\section{xx}
\subsection{CPU}
\subsection{Registers}
\subsection{Memory}
```

any ideas why this doesn't work?

As mentioned above..

Comment: Did you test the code from your question before posting? It neither compiles (missing `\end{document}`) nor would it produce a toc (no frames in your sections)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `allowframebreaks` option to your outline frame and beamer will automatically break the frame into multiple slides:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

%%%% graphics
%\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%START THEME SETTINGS
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\title{stuff}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}


\section{x}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Introduction}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Use Cases}\begin{frame}\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------
\section{xyz}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Introduction}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Use cases}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Hyypervisors}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Hypervisors Types}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Memory Management}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Memory Overcommitment}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Memory Compression}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Memory Transparent Page Sharing}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
%\newpage %<- this doesn't work!


%--------------------------------------------
\section{xy}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Motivation}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Virtualization}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Emulation}\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\section{xx}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{CPU}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Registers}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Memory}\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can manually split your table of contents to get more fine control of the break point:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

%%%% graphics
%\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%START THEME SETTINGS
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\title{stuff}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
    \only<1>{\tableofcontents[sections={1-2}]}
    \only<2>{\tableofcontents[sections={3-4}]}
\end{frame}


\section{x}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Introduction}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Use Cases}\begin{frame}\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------
\section{xyz}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Introduction}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Use cases}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Hyypervisors}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Hypervisors Types}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Memory Management}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Memory Overcommitment}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Memory Compression}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Memory Transparent Page Sharing}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
%\newpage %<- this doesn't work!


%--------------------------------------------
\section{xy}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Motivation}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Virtualization}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Emulation}\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\section{xx}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{CPU}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Registers}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\subsection{Memory}\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]